# Excel VBA to Insert the value from below cell

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

If the "SES New/Continuation" is Continuation then i need to add the highlighted values in the above + 1 cell (ie Line 19) likewise where ever its highlithted we need to add to the above cell + 1 cell and then delete the continuation row.

Comment: welcome to SO. this is not a free coding service platform. show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill a blank cell with the value below that cell, run this script.

```
Sub FillBlanks()
    With Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[+1]C"
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to do the opposite, fill a blank cell with the value above, run this script.

```
Sub FillBlanks()
    With Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    End With
End Sub
```